# Why can't I get encodeURIComponent() to work in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

It works in the other browsers, converts the `&` character into `%26` which is the expected output.

```
var CustomerID = "1234A&B";
let qString = "CustomerID=" + encodeURIComponent(CustomerID);
```

The output in IE11, Edge and Chrome is `CustomerID=1234A%26B` which is what I expect, but in Firefox it's like the method didn't take: `CustomerID=1234A&B`. This is a problem for me because now the server is getting parameter `B` with a value of `null` because it's translating the ampersand into a query string delimiter and interpreting `B` as a second parameter.

Is my implementation incorrect? I'm using Firefox 64.0.2 (January 9, 2019).

Comment: It works for me in Firefox.

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: Ok I'm gonna test on other machines, maybe it's just me :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a dumbass. Before I was using attribute routing and just passing the values as a route parameter (this is MVC on the backend). Then I changed it to use query strings because the parameters have special characters and attribute routing requires deeper potentially risky modifications to allow special characters as parameters.

Anyway, the parameter name in the query string was mislabeled. It wasn't a problem when I was just using the parameter value in attribute routing, but with query strings you need to specify exactly what the parameter name is.